# Summernote tooltip icon not showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, summernote

In my summernote editor I have the problem that the font icon isn't working while I see it back in the html. I am wondering how to fix this issue?

[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem a while ago and solved by:

1. The fonts used by summernote is not the bootstrap one. They have their own font directory. One can check the console (Ctrl+Shift+I) in web browser for any error. One may have to edit the summernote.css file if they are not located in the default folder for Summernote like adding "../" in front of all the font references at the top of the css file.For my application, I had put it under /static/css/font for the server to find it.
2. To check whether the server is able to find the directory, one can also check the network by right click -> Inspect element-> change to network tab:

[image: The network tab in browser]